# Scrapy CrawlSpider memory leak

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, memory-leaks, scrapy

I have a multiprocessed spider launched from a python script that leaks memory and crashes the server no matter the amount of memory configured.

Here is the code to its simplest but still leaking :

```
class wb8(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'wb8'
    def __init__(self, bdd_id, domain, cleaned_domain, *a, **kw):
        self.domain = domain
        self.bdd_id = bdd_id
        self.start_urls = [domain]
        self.allowed_domains = [cleaned_domain]
        self.rules = (
            Rule(
                LinkExtractor(
                    restrict_xpaths = ["//footer//a | //a[not(//footer)]"],
                    unique=True
                ), 
                callback='parse_test',
                follow=True),
        )
        super().__init__(*a,**kw)

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        return self.parse_test(response)

    def parse_test(self,response):
        yield
```

I pass the target url (`domain`) & allowed_domains (`cleaned_domain`) from a `process.crawl`. I set a rule that goes for all links in the footer, if footer does not exists, goes for all links on the page.

I am pretty sure this is the portion that leaks because I tried to convert the `CrawlSpider` to a basic `scrapy.Spider`, all processed the same with same targets :

```
class wb8(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wb8'
    def __init__(self, bdd_id, domain, cleaned_domain):
        
        self.domain = domain
        self.bdd_id = bdd_id
        self.start_urls = [domain]
        self.allowed_domains = [cleaned_domain]
        
    def parse(self,response):
        pass
```

The memory used does not exceed 1GB.

Some tests to debug the `CrawlSpider` :

From the scrapy tools `prefs()` in telnet console, just before the server crash :

```
HtmlResponse                      143   oldest: 310s ago
Request                           149   oldest: 314s ago
Selector                          141   oldest: 309s ago
Wb7Item                             1   oldest: 1s ago
wb8                                 1   oldest: 318s a
```

More or less than 100 responses cannot eat many GB of memory. My targets are classic small websites.

Using Pympler :

Before launching the crawler :

```
============================ | =========== | ============
                         str |       15158 |      2.94 MB
                        dict |        4439 |      2.03 MB
                        code |        5379 |    928.85 KB
                        type |         938 |    740.05 KB
                       tuple |        3563 |    203.95 KB
          wrapper_descriptor |        2217 |    155.88 KB
                         set |         142 |    110.45 KB
  builtin_function_or_method |        1482 |    104.20 KB
           method_descriptor |        1390 |     97.73 KB
                 abc.ABCMeta |          96 |     94.62 KB
                     weakref |        1247 |     87.68 KB
                        list |         357 |     83.88 KB
           getset_descriptor |         948 |     59.25 KB
                         int |        1870 |     51.99 KB
                   frozenset |         124 |     48.41 KB
```

Right before the crash where memory is full :

```
                       types |   # objects |   total size
============================ | =========== | ============
                        list |       15195 |      4.72 MB
                         str |       29978 |      3.95 MB
                        dict |        4439 |      2.03 MB
                        code |        5379 |    929.16 KB
                        type |         938 |    740.05 KB
                       tuple |        3566 |    204.12 KB
          wrapper_descriptor |        2217 |    155.88 KB
                         int |        5218 |    143.54 KB
                         set |         142 |    110.45 KB
  builtin_function_or_method |        1482 |    104.20 KB
           method_descriptor |        1390 |     97.73 KB
                 abc.ABCMeta |          96 |     94.62 KB
                     weakref |        1247 |     87.68 KB
           getset_descriptor |         948 |     59.25 KB
                   frozenset |         124 |     48.41 KB
```

The total size is still negligible.

I made an objgraph of one `CrawlerProcess()` :
[image]
Still nothing fancy there

I am currently running out of ideas to debug this. I am guessing the issue comes from the definition of my `CrawlSpider` class `wb8` but can't find how

Comment: If you can expand your question slightly to include a minimal reproducible example (which should include instructions on how to run it as well as a complete program and any needed input) it will be more likely that you will get an answer to to your questions.

Comment: After some tests, I realized that it wasn't a memory leak, my crawler just needs a lot of memory. It should be the case of crawlers following many links with a depth >= 2 as many objects are kept in memory during the spider's life

Comment: @IndiaSke Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm also facing a similar issue.

Comment: @Shibiraj After some work on similar projects I resolved the issue simply by increasing ressources but mostly by limiting the crawler depth and maximum links it can follow by page. There is no leaking memory except that all responses are stored in memory (from what I saw) during the crawler's life. If you encounter a website with a lot of links to follow and an important depth for the crawler, the memory required increases, a lot. Now, I mostly use the classic scrapy.spider and not the CrawlSpider